# I'm trying to manipulate the DOM by adding images from an API

Tags: javascript, api, dom

For a homework assignment, I'm trying to figure out how to get the images from an API, retrieved as a JSON object and then extract the images from it and insert them into the DOM. My tutorials are fairly unclear on how to do it. ANy ideas? I really need help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think i need something like the code here: https://bcc0b04ffd91970cc7acae574acf488e--8080.nt.run/

but it will take my local server API (http://www.jbrcodes.com/oc/wiki/project-notes/leverage-external-apis) and return JSON info which I would like to print to the DOM